# How to programatically change Firebase google JSON for different build variants?

Tags: android, firebase, android-productflavors

In general to switch between build variants you can use `productFlavors`. But I want to change these variants in runtime with button.

There is `ServerType` enum class containing multiple build variants. 
I have `Server` class with `apiKey` and `url` attribute.

Inside those variants are `Server` objects.(You can use multiple APIs per build variant).

This enum class has same functionality as `productFlavors`. I can change those addresses in runtime and set active variant from dropdown menu. This will affect every API call in my app. What I cant change is what `google.json` is chosen by Firebase. Is there any way how to tell Firebase to use different json? I have 4 variants and jsons are located inside each variant file in project.

Firebase is choosing automatically google.json based on what `Build Variant` is selected while building the app.

Answer (score 1):

The choice of which google-services.json file to use is always determined at build time by the Google play services plugin.  It is never determined at runtime.

If you need to change project configurations at runtime, you will not be able to use that plugin or its google-services.json configuration file.  You will need to find another way to put all the possible different configurations in your app at build time, then select which one to use at runtime.  You will have to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp() yourself instead of accepting the default configuration.  There are a lot of strategies to do this, but I will recommend you [start here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/take-control-of-your-firebase-init-on.html).

Comment: I've used `productFlavors` in my app for different variants. In my `Application`class where I initializing my `Api` class I choose which `ServerType` from enum class load based on `BuildConfig.FLAVOR` value. But I want to change `BuildVariant` in runtime. Is it possible? If I click on different option from dropdown in my app in runtime, I want to change `Build Variant`, restart app and load `ServerType` when `Application` class will be created. Because now i can change my variant only in AndroidStudio (left corner BuildVariants). For testing purposes I want to allow user to change variants.

Comment: And this change will create second version of my App. Which I dont want to

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the multiple environment directories? Which allows you to put several different `google.json` files for different build variants. ([help from firebase site](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#support_multiple_environments_in_your_android_application)).

This is also a dedicated directory, so not that dynamic, but this is all that the Firebase can handle on runtime.

Comment: The OP is asking how to select a project configuration at runtime, not a build time using build flavors.